# iOS Chrome share after Facebook login OAuth

Tags: javascript, facebook

After getting an error on iOS Chrome for sharing a URL, so I amended my code so it opens a window and checks for login status via OAuth.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.1

```
$singleSocialLinks.on('click', 'a.fb', function() {
    if( navigator.userAgent.match('CriOS') ) {
        window.open('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri='+ document.location.href +'&scope=email,publish_actions', '', null);
    } else {
  // FB.login(null, {scope: 'email,public_profile'});
     FB.ui({
       method: 'share',
       href: document.location.href
     }, 
     function(response){
        console.log(response);
     });
   }      
});
```

At the moment it goes back to the same URL as expected with a 'code' response_type in the url. Do i need use this in order to share? Is there a callback or other facebook parameters i can use after user auth has been confirmed? Also at what point does the SDK become available in IOS chrome if at all?

I've tried differnt url's, scopes and most of the other parameters too but I seem to be missing some obvious syntax at the is point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Me too faced similar problem when we developed fb share in our project using fb.ui.  So I tired the following workaround and it solves me the problem of sharing article with facebook authentication. The only problem I faced was since I have used window.open all my fb authentication, share dialog box and article re-direction was done in new tab.

Below is my code:

```
jsq("element class").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  if(navigator.userAgent.match('CriOS')){
window.open('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id='+fbAppid + '&display=popup&redirect_uri='+ location.href +'&href='+location.href+'&scope=email,publish_actions', '', null);
  }else{
        FB.ui({
      method: 'share',
      href: location.href
    }, function(response){
    if(typeof response !='undefined'){

      # method to be called.
    }
    });
  }
  });
  if(navigator.userAgent.match('CriOS')){
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
         #method to be called.
      }
    });
  }
```